# Use content of FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to add a file import function to an admin webpage where a CSV file will be imported from a local C: drive

I've just realized that `string filePath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);` doesn't actually allow the client path to be read and only gives the filename.

```
protected void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<CSVFile> entries = new List<CSVFile>();

  string filePath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
  using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
  {

    //Other code
  }

}
```

Currently the line `TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath)` gives an error as I can't get the full path to the CSV.

Is it possible to load the contents of `FileUpload1` into variable `parser` instead? I can see the control has content but not sure how or if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileName` property is simply the filename the browser sent, and is not yet physically stored on the server.  To do so, you'll need to save it first:

```
string filePath = String.Format({0}{1}", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), FileUpload1.FileName); // Save to temp directory
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
{
  //...
}
File.Delete(filePath); // Delete the file if you're done with it
```

Also, if `TextFieldParser` can take in a `System.IO.Stream`, you won't even need to save the file to disk first:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(FileUpload1.FileContent)) // Read stream
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to avoid saving files to the server. Thank you.

Comment: @ooo: You don't have to save the file, but you'll need to change your parser to receive the data stream as parameter

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that the file is not stored yet on the server so there is no path. `FileName` is just that: a file name and not a full path.

If you require the file to exist on the file system in order to parse it, you'll need to first save it.